# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01

Tags: android-studio

I am getting below error in my new Android studio version basic hello world is also not building in gradle. cloud you please help on the same.

**This is the error I am getting in new android studio version :**

[image: This is the error I am getting in new android studio version]

**My gradle file is as below**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "payments.com.java.payments"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**This is the logs i am getting**

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

Comment: share your gradle file. And instead of pasting a screenshot, paste the stack trace in text.

Comment: I suggest moving to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` libraries instead of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` as the support library will not be getting anymore updates after 28.0.0

Comment: Updated question with gradle file and logs

Comment: @tyczj That didnt help. I still have the issue.and it is not just with appcompat

all of below elements are failing

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

Answer (score 10):

Check your internet connectivity. For me it was just internet connectivity problem. If you are under a proxy server. Go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior >System Settings >HTTP Proxy and enter your proxy details there. Use the check connection option to verify your connection. Here is a reference to my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.oops.pk.birthday_card"
       minSdkVersion 23
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner 
       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
             'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
     }
}

dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
     core:3.0.2'
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `Shadowsocks` proxy in China, open `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and comment https host and port

```
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
```

after that, create new project again or build your project again, done

Answer (score 2):

My colleague ran into same problem. We solve this issue by deleting **.android** , **.AndroidStudiox.x** and **.gradle** folders.This will delete all current android settings and will download again when open android studio. make sure android studio must be close.[image]

Comment: I tried it. This one works. thank you @Vishal G. Gohel

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me.

Go to - build.gradle (Module: app)

Search for (for me) :

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+’

Replace it with:

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'

Hit 'Sync' or 'Try Again'.

Reference:

[Before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnmmZ.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHyni.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use :

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'`

The `.+` will match any version of appcompat-v7:28. Currently there are `28.0.0-alpha1 and 28.0.0-alpha3` in [Google's Maven](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) repository.

Answer (score 1):

You nee to disable Offline mode if you've checked it. File > Settings > Build,Execution  and deployment > Gradle - Uncheck offline mode and apply.

Also, please check your internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
delete your gradle http proxy
C:\Users***.gradle\gradle.properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFhwJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason

   If you are in China, the reason about this maybe be your `Android Studio` hadn't set the proxy correctly. So when you built the application, the `gradle` can't access to the [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) to download the dependencies(such as support library).

   And notice: The `Android Studio` is allow socks proxy and http proxy, but the `gradle` is only allow http proxy. So you may find that your `Android Studio` can download the SDK or even upgrade if you had set socks proxy in Android Studio. But when you built, the `gradle` can't download the support library because you are use socks proxy now.
2. How to fix

   If you use `Shadowsocks` proxy. Follow this:

   - For Mac OS:

     You should download [ShadowsocksX-NG](https://github.com/shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG/releases) not ShadowsocksX, because ShadowsocksX may not compatible with the Android Studio.
     And the `ShadowsocksX-NG` is use socks5 proxy, the Android Studio is access socks5 proxy, but remember `gradle` didn't.

     You can see the ShadowsocksX-NG's proxy info in the `Preferences Setting`, you can find that:

     - local socks5 host: 127.0.0.1
     - local socks5 port: 1086
     - local PAC port: 1089
     - local http port: 1087

     So you should set the http proxy in Android Studio like this:

     [image: set http proxy in AS on Mac]
   - For Windows:

     You can download the [Shadowsocks-windows](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-windows/releases) and have a look at the correct host and port, and then set them to the Android Studio proxy.

     - If you select http proxy, you may set like this:

       [image: set http proxy in AS on Windows]

       And if it still can't work, try to add these below codes to the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file:

       > systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
       >
       > systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
       >
       > systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
       >
       > systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
     - If you select socks proxy, you may set like this:

       [image: set socks proxy in AS on Windows]

       And if you use socks proxy, it may still can't work, trying to add these codes to the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, like this:

       [image: set socks proxy for gradle]

       The purpose of this is to set gradle proxy.

   Hopefully it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other working (not error) Android Studio Project,

You can check the settings of `build.gradle` under your `Project - app` and look for this line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:***'
```

Is your working SDK version in your working project, then replace your

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

with the working SDK version (***)

if you don't have any working (without error) project, you can try mine:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Hopefully this can solve your problem, because it solved mine just now.

Comment: I still have the issue

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Youtube video **which I created** as a solution to this Problem,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAYtPzjDSQU&feature=youtu.be

This is how your Gradle Should look.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "payments.banamex.citi.com.banamexpayments"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: You have to add disclosure when linking your own youtube videos. Otherwise, this could be considered spam.

Comment: Thanks @Zoe for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error.I found a solution.I hope it helps you too.

Go to **build.gradle(Module:app)** and **delete**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Answer (score 0):

if not 28 version supported means change the complied and target version to 27

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem and it is fixed by replacing a dependency file from previous properly working project. Just replace the depndency file in the gradle by another project's dependency gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I created a new project and androidx was marked but I was connected to internet. The simple solution was to just connect to internet and sync the project again. Voila it builds with no error. You can try that.

Answer (score -1):

"Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02."

This was the error i was getting in the gradle and is simply solved just by connecting to the internet.